# TemplateDoesNotExist with slight twist

Tags: django, python-2.7, templates

Okay so getting the standard template does not exist error with django 1.5.4. I'm fairly sure I have everything set up correctly.
The project is `tango_with_django` with an app called `rango`. This app is then meant to take a template, `"index.html"` from this directory `"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\GitHub\tangowithdjango\tango_with_django_project\templates\rango"`.
The project is the second folder, I realise it's a little messy but the first folder only contains the second.
My `setting.py`

```python
import os 
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir) 
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH) 
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates') 
DEBUG = True 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG 
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader', ) 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates". # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows. # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths. 
TEMPLATE_PATH, )
```

*EDIT* The TemplateDoesNotExist error also misses out t's in the dir path. Unsure if this is just a display issue,

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/
C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\GitHub  angowithdjango  ango_with_django_project    emplates
ango\index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\GitHub  angowithdjango  ango_with_django_project    emplates
ango\index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 139
Python Executable:  C:\python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Documents\\GitHub\\tangowithdjango\\tango_with_django_project',
 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\python27\\lib',
 'C:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\python27']
Server time:    Mon, 26 Jan 2015 14:11:57 +0000
```

Comment: Your TEMPLATE_DIRS seems to be empty. because everythong there is commented out by #

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader', )
```

You have commented out the closing bracket for your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

Comment: Sorry that was me when I was attempting to source the error, even when not commented out the problem persists. Thanks for the reply so quickly though

Comment: @RyanMckenna What do you get if you print `TEMPLATE_PATH`?

Comment: @RyanMckenna Also, how do you specify the template to load? In my tests the `Exception Value` is a path relative to the template directory, not an absolute path.